# Optimal network layout w/ static ips

Tags: networking, home-networking, static-ip

Ive been trying to set this up correctly for a while, and this is as close to successful as I've been. This layout has worked but is not reliable. Every once in a while access to the outside internet drops and requires a reboot of the modem and access point to fix.

I've diagramed the network for your viewing pleasure (masking out my static IPs)

I have Comcast businness so that I am able to get static IPs.

[image: Network Diagram]

I was experimenting with static routing for a while, since the server and laptops are on different subnets (255.255.255.0 vs 255.255.255.248)

So, what I need to know is if there is anything in here that could be causing the random outages.

If the best course of action is to rip this up and configure it another way, so be it, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: IMO if it works for a while then it's setup properly, and you need to try replacing the devices you find you need to reboot to fix the problem.  Also, please separate this out into multiple questions. One about outages, one about the server having an internal IP, etc.

Comment: Question is split. I'll go through and begin looking for replacement devices, but I have some reservations about that. Comcast was here a few weeks ago and they gave us a new modem. We were told that this wasn't a refurbished one, but a brand new modem. When the outages occur I can still access them modem through the AP, which leads me to believe that the AP is not bad.

Comment: when the connection drops, do ALL devices lose Internet?  When it happens, have you tried rebooting JUST one device (or the other)?  When it happens: Can you ping the modem/router from any device?  Can you ping your ISP-given gateway from inside?  Can you communicate with your router or server from the outside? Can all internal devices communicate with each other?

Comment: Next time it goes out I will check to confirm, but I believe all devices lose internet. I know for sure all those on WiFi do, and I'm confident that those connected directly to the modem do. Yes I can ping the AP, and I can ping the modem. I am unable to connect to the server from the outside. I will check about internal communication when it goes out again.